# Read data from XElement that has elements mixed with plain content

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

XElement has the following value:

```
<parent><child>text inside element</child>and plain content</parent>
```

How can I convert it to a string that contains: "text inside element and plain content".

**What I've tried already?**

I tired to use `xElement.Value`, but this concats the two nodes without putting a space between them: "text inside elementand plain content".

Comment: No repro. I see `.Value` getting a lot of spaces and a newline.

Comment: I guess xml should be something like `<parent><child>text inside element</child>and plain content</parent>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Text you are looking for is stored in nodes of type XText. So you can get at these nodes like this:

```
xElement.DescendantNodes()
        .OfType<XText>()
        .Select(t => t.Value)
```

That would give you this result:

```
text inside element 
and plain content
```

You could then concatenate these as you wish (for example with `String.Join`).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, if he wants to ensure the values have exactly one space between them, this would be a good idea.